# Script only works when another script is commented in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-video

I'm really new to javascript and I've been working on a fairly difficult project for be being such a newbie when it comes to javascript.
The project consists of a video editor, I have a toolbox with a couple of images and a video element side by side with a canvas.
When the video starts to play It has to be drawn onto the canvas, and the images on the toolbox need to be able to be dragged onto the canvas.
I've been able to accomplish this but I am facing a problem.
When the script that allows me to drag and drop an image onto the canvas is not commented the script that draws the video on the canvas suddenly stops working.
In other words the video only gets drawn when the other script is commented.

This is the script I'm using to drag the image onto the canvas:

```
  < script >
    (function() {
      var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
      window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
    })();

  var imagesOnCanvas = [];

  function renderScene() {
    requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0,
      canvas.width,
      canvas.height
    );


    for (var x = 0, len = imagesOnCanvas.length; x < len; x++) {
      var obj = imagesOnCanvas[x];
      obj.context.drawImage(obj.image, obj.x, obj.y);

    }
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);

  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
      var downX = e.offsetX,
        downY = e.offsetY;

      // scan images on canvas to determin if event hit an object
      for (var x = 0, len = imagesOnCanvas.length; x < len; x++) {
        var obj = imagesOnCanvas[x];
        if (!isPointInRange(downX, downY, obj)) {
          continue;
        }

        startMove(obj, downX, downY);
        break;
      }

    }
  }, false);

  function startMove(obj, downX, downY) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    var origX = obj.x,
      origY = obj.y;
    canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
      var moveX = e.offsetX,
        moveY = e.offsetY;
      var diffX = moveX - downX,
        diffY = moveY - downY;


      obj.x = origX + diffX;
      obj.y = origY + diffY;
    }

    canvas.onmouseup = function() {
      // stop moving
      canvas.onmousemove = function() {};
    }
  }

  function isPointInRange(x, y, obj) {
    return !(x < obj.x ||
      x > obj.x + obj.width ||
      y < obj.y ||
      y > obj.y + obj.height);
  }


  function allowDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(e) {
    //store the position of the mouse relativly to the image position
    e.dataTransfer.setData("mouse_position_x", e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft);
    e.dataTransfer.setData("mouse_position_y", e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop);

    e.dataTransfer.setData("image_id", e.target.id);
  }

  function drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var image = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData("image_id"));

    var mouse_position_x = e.dataTransfer.getData("mouse_position_x");
    var mouse_position_y = e.dataTransfer.getData("mouse_position_y");

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    imagesOnCanvas.push({
      context: ctx,
      image: image,
      x: e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft - mouse_position_x,
      y: e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop - mouse_position_y,
      width: image.offsetWidth,
      height: image.offsetHeight
    });

  }

  function convertCanvasToImage() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

    var image_src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    window.open(image_src);

  }
  < /script>
```

And here is the script to draw the video onto the canvas:

```
  < script >
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  });

  video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    var $this = this; //cache
    (function loop() {
      if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {
        ctx.drawImage($this, 0, 0);
        setTimeout(loop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps
      }
    })();
  }, 0); < /script>
```

> NOTE: The first script is in the head section before the canvas and video element.
>   The second script is in the body element right after the video and canvas elements.

This is my canvas, toolbox images and video element:

```
<div id="denv">
  <div class="container-fluid" style="display: flex;align-items: flex-start;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:lavender;">Figuras
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item "><img id="img1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png'></li>
          <li class="list-group-item "><img id="img2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png'></li>
          <li class="list-group-item "><img id="img3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png'></li>
          <li class="list-group-item "><img id="img4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png'></li>
          <li class="list-group-item "><img id="img5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" src='http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png'></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <video id="video" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv" controls="autoplay"></video>
      <canvas id="canvas" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid gray"></canvas>
```

I feel that this amount of code here makes it a little bit unreadable and hard to understand so... here is a link for the entire code.

> I've commented where the scripts are and what the do: https://codeshare.io/2BAqX9

The bottom line is that I can't understand why one script only works when the other is commented out, I know the two work fine.

If you have any questions or something that I can improve in my question please let me know.

PS: I know it's a lot of code but I feel that If I didn't provide all of the scripts and html it would be really hard for anyone to stop a problem

Thank you for your time

> EDIT: JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awhau99t/ 
>   didn't separate JS from HTML because I wouldn't have a "working" example to show due to the way the functions are built

Comment: You should consider using something like https://jsfiddle.net/ to make a working example of your code, so it's easier for others to understand what you're trying to to.

Furthermore you should take a look at your browsers dev-console to see if any errors show up there.

Comment: @I will provide a link to JSFiddle, I've checked the console and no error show up

Comment: @morten.c See the edit please